# Finding special key data of bluetooth HID mouse with AHKHID

Tags: autohotkey, hid

I have a Mad catz mouse9 bluetooth mouse. It's software isn't very good. So I have been using ahk, with special keys programmed to shift + f12 or something (to emulate f22 etc. mad catz software does not support f22 directly)

This is not a very good solution, and sometimes causes problems.

So I wanted to not use mad catz software.

I have tried AHKHID's example 2 to find what calls are being made.

When I read for mouse I can get data for special keys, but they seem emty. so there is data being polled but I do not know how to differentiate between different keys

[image: "data on screen"]

I have tried AHKHID_GetInputData but it seems to not work for mouses.

Is there somemethod to get raw data?

I have also looked for other HID devices connected, but they do not register anything.

I am not good at programming (or scripting in this case), so sorry for any stupid mistakes :)

Example code: https://github.com/jleb/AHKHID/blob/master/examples/example_2.ahk

Comment: While this may not be ideal, have you tried the first recommendation under "Alternative solutions" at the bottom of the help page: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Unfortunately that causes issues with some of the programs i use.